# How do I switch modes inside a user-defined lua function?

Tags: neovim, visual-mode, vimscript-lua

I want to write a command to do the following:

1. Make a visual selection.
2. Call a command on the visual selection.

By way of example, I'd like to call `vat` to visually select around the current tag, and then use [Limelight](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim) to highlight it.

*Attempt #1:*

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('HighlightTagBlock',
    function()
        vim.cmd.normal("vat")
        vim.cmd("'<,'>Limelight")
    end,
    { nargs = 0 }
)
```

*Attempt #2:*

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('HighlightTagBlock',
    function()
        vim.cmd.normal("vat")
        vim.cmd.visual("Limelight")
    end,
    { nargs = 0 }
)
```

Neither of these works as expected. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know neovim api, but `<Plug>(Limelight)` defined as visual mapping in Limelight might work:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('HighlightTagBlock',
    function()
        vim.cmd.normal("vat")
        vim.cmd.visual("<Plug>(Limelight)")
    end,
    { nargs = 0 }
)
```

Comment: Best I can tell, it seems like this is equivalent to the `vim.cmd.visual("Limelight")` version.